# Как идентифицировать текстовые файлы в unix системах через терминал?

Tags: unix, консоль, файлы

Стоит задание найти количество строк в каждом файле текущей директории,  упорядочить результат и записать в файл.

Проблема в том, что я не знаю как идентифицировать все текстовые файлы в папке.

Comment: Считайте пробелы,возвраты каретки, табуляцию в каждом файле. Если больше определенного процента от размера, файл текстовый. Эвристика конечно, но быть может подойдет. Большие файлы можно игнорировать. wc и grep в помощь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я бы предложил вот такое извращение:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
     -exec sh -c "file -bi '{}' | grep -q ^text/ && echo '{}'" \; \
  | xargs wc -l | head -n -1 | sort -gk 1 > line_counts.txt
```

Что тут творится:

- `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f` — ищем в текущем каталоге (не ломясь глубже) все файлы (`-type f`)
- `-exec sh -c "…" \;` — для каждого из них выполняем команду `sh -c "…"` (вместо «`{}`» будет подставлено имя файла). Смысл сего действа в том, что просто так мы пайпу в find не засунем, оно не поймет, вот и приходится вызывать шелл.
- `file -bi '{}'` — определяем MIME-тип файла (`-i`), само имя файла не выводим (`-q`). Это может быть не самый точный вариант определения, см. примечания ниже.
- `grep -q ^text/` — выбираем строчки, которые начинаются с «`text/`», но ничего не выводим (`-q`), а только сообщаем кодом выхода, нашлось что-то или нет
- `&& echo '{}'` — если нашлось, то будет выполнена правая часть `&&` и выведено имя файла.
- `xargs wc -l` — все поступающие имена файлов будут поданы аргументами `wc`, которое и посчитает строки (`-l`).
- `head -n -1` — обрезаем последнюю строчку, с суммарным результатом
- `sort -gk 1` — численно (`-g`) сортируем по первому полю (`-k 1`)

Возможны вариации. В частности, думаю, не одним `^text/` все ограничивается (некоторые файлы, представляющие собой текст в UTF-8 имеют MIME-типы в `application/*`, но есть и всякие `application/octet-stream`, которые, вообще говоря, ни разу не текстовые), так что, может быть, лучше подойдет что-то в духе `file -b '{}' | grep -Fq ' text'`. Так же, если файлов будет очень много, а имена у них длинные — придется вызывать wc не один раз, а по разу для каждого файла, «`xargs -I '{}' wc -l '{}'`».

Да, я использовал, в основном, GNU'шные утилиты (GNU findutils, GNU coreutils, GNU grep), если не считать BSD'шного `file`. На не-GNU системах могут оказаться другие утилиты, которые могут какой-нибудь опции и не понять, или понять не так. В общем, YMMV, если что — смотрите в документацию.

Все это, правда, сломается если какой-нибудь любитель *странного* создаст файл, с именем, содержащим символ перевода строки (`\n`). Тогда пайпа, начиная с `xargs` сломается. Чтобы решить, придется добавлять еще `&& echo -e '\x00'` (или как-то так) и добавить `xargs` аргумент `-0` (`--null`).

Comment: плюс за изврат) тоже когдато так развлекался)))

Comment: Юникс рулит

Comment: Изврат чуть проще, может не очень надежно, но пишется влет

    wc -l `file * | grep text | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr -d :` | sort -gk 1

Comment: @avp: Да, но оно сломается на первом же файле, с именем, содержащим пробелы и двоеточия. У меня такой оказался как раз в той директории, где тестировал.

Comment: А что не работает? Ну, там (кроме двоеточий, пробелов и т.п.) еще последнюю строку (total) надо удалять. 

Я же написал, это просто влет набито. Если реальная задача, то надо подумать, главное определиться, что считать текстовым файлом. Если имена вообще любые, то я бы не мучался, а на Си написал (если тип файла правильно утилита file определяет, то вызывал бы ее через popen).